# Delphi - JPEG error #53

Tags: delphi, jpeg

TImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('File.jpg');

but i got **JPEG error #53** ! what is the reason for this error?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

my problem solved by using **TAdvPicture** componenet.

Comment: Can you please mention how you solved your problem by using TAdvPicture,  I am also getting similar type of error , but image not corrupted at all I can view image data in SQLite and can extract image properly at another software. Not sure why I am getting `JPEG Error #53`

Comment: TAdvPicture just won't raise the error, it will display the picture as best it can, and then stop.  I have also reverted to this as a solution, since I can't stop the error using a Try... Except, and I dont' really want to have to change the code in the Vcl.  TAdvPicture  is a component by TMS Software (this is not an advertisement)

Comment: If anyone need a component could be find, If you solved this problem in a correct way with enough explanation and then told about some component I had no problem, but this: you just described an issue as a question and suddenly you find a component and SHAZAM anything just work!!! This is not proper manner here.

Comment: Not even linking the component: [1.3 from 2003](https://web.archive.org/web/20050210002204/https://www.tmssoftware.com/advpicture.zip) and [10.7 from 2022](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advpic.asp)

Answer (score 10):

This usually comes when the Jpeg image is downloaded from Internet and the download is not 100% complete. It can happen even with TImage.
Unfortunately Jpeg do not have a checksum to check against.

The only think you can do is whenever this error is thrown to catch it and display more responsive message like "The image is corrupted.".

Since this raises the error:

```
procedure JpegError(cinfo: j_common_ptr); {$IFDEF LINUX} cdecl; export; {$ENDIF}
begin
  raise EJPEG.CreateFmt(sJPEGError,[cinfo^.err^.msg_code]);
end;
```

where

```
sJPEGError = 'JPEG error #%d';
```

you can try to catch EJPEG error and check for #53 within the message.

Since EJPEG inherits from EInvalidGraphic you can simply catch it with

```
catch
  on E: EInvalidGraphic do
  begin
    ShowMessage('Image file is corrupted.')
  end;
end;
```

Comment: [JFIF/JPEG files can be checked against incompleteness: segment `EOI` should occur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure). Also file corruption is not limited to failed downloads.

Answer (score 5):

Does it occur to a single jpeg image or with all jpegs you try?

JPEG error #53 error will come due to Insufficient memory.

If file is corrupted, this error may occur.

So opening this image in paint or photoshop and re-saving it in jpeg can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please try following to solve 'JPEG error #53' if its occur at this statement `TImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('File.jpg')`

```
TImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('File.jpg');
```

Note that File File.jpg should be exist at provided location.

Comment: This is just wrong. How could a `TBitmap` expect to load a JPEG ? `TBitmap` can load, uhm, bitmaps. [the downvote is not mine though]

Answer (score 2):

I also had the #53 error.
It turned out that the error only occurred after I had erroneously saved a bitmap with the *.jpg extension.
The obvious solution was to turn that bitmap into a jpeg and save it then :-).