# Is there a TSVGImage class to load an SVG image via TMemoryStream into a TImage.Picture?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

We are using SVG images in our application.

Here's what our code looks like for JPEG images (it's a working sample from our application, it is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200252/)):

```pascal
Var
  memoryStreamFile: TMemoryStream;
  blobFieldFile:TBlobField;  
  JPEGImage: TJPEGImage;
  //ImageJPEG:TImage is a TImage on the form

blobFieldFile:=ClientDataSet.fieldbyName('Image') as TblobField ;
memoryStreamFile := TMemoryStream.Create;

blobFieldFile.SaveToStream(memoryStreamFile);
memoryStreamFile.Position:=0;

JPEGImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
try
  JPEGImage.LoadFromStream(memoryStreamFile);
  ImageJPEG.Picture.Assign(JPEGImage);
finally
  JPEGImage.Free;
end;
```

I would like to do the same as above for SVG images:

```pascal
Var
  memoryStreamFile: TMemoryStream;
  blobFieldFile:TBlobField;  
  SVGImage: TSVGImage; -->>This does not exist
  //ImageSVG:TImage is a TImage on the form

blobFieldFile:=ClientDataSet.fieldbyName('Image') as TblobField ;
memoryStreamFile := TMemoryStream.Create;

blobFieldFile.SaveToStream(memoryStreamFile);
memoryStreamFile.Position:=0;

SVGImage := TSVGImage.Create;//Sample of how I would envision it to work. Obviously this does not exist
try
  SVGImage.LoadFromStream(memoryStreamFile);
  ImageSVG.Picture.Assign(SVGImage);
finally
  SVGImage.Free;
end;
```

We basically generate the SVG code in text format and would like to load the text into `TImage`.

Is there a way to stream this that I'm not seeing?

I know that I can take our SVG text and save it to file, and then do `TImage.Picture.LoadFromFile()`, but I prefer to do `TImage.Picture.LoadFromStream()`.

I know that there are other components that could be used, ie [Delphi SVG](https://www.bverhue.nl/delphisvg/)  (we currently use this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ClientDataSet.CreateBlobStream()` instead of `blobFieldFile.SaveToStream()`, then you don't need the `TMemoryStream` at all:

```pascal
var
  Blob: TField;
  Stream: TStream;
  JPEG: TJPEGImage;
begin
  Blob := ClientDataSet.FieldByName('Image');
  Stream := ClientDataSet.CreateBlobStream(Blob, bmRead);
  try
    JPEG := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      JPEG.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      Image.Picture.Assign(JPEG);
    finally
      JPEG.Free;
    end; 
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As for loading an SVG image, all you need is a `TGraphic` class that supports SVG. The VCL has no such class available natively, but the [Delphi SVG](https://www.bverhue.nl/delphisvg/) package you are already using does - [`TSVG2Graphic`](https://www.bverhue.nl/SVGDoc23/Delphi%20SVG%20control%20version%202_3.html#idTsvg2graphic):

```pascal
var
  Blob: TField;
  Stream: TStream;
  SVG: TSVG2Graphic;
begin
  Blob := ClientDataSet.FieldByName('Image');
  Stream := ClientDataSet.CreateBlobStream(Blob, bmRead);
  try
    SVG := TSVG2Graphic.Create;
    try
      SVG.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      Image.Picture.Assign(SVG);
    finally
      SVG.Free;
    end; 
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```