# Load jpeg image from file

Tags: delphi, jpeg, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm saving a picture from `Image` component and when try load into `TJpeg` have **error #53**. How fix?

> Exception EJPEG in module myprogram.exe at 002F744F. JPEG error #53

```
var
 JpegImage: TJpegImage;
begin
  Image1.Picture.SaveToFile('test.jpg');
  JpegImage := TJpegImage.Create;
  try
   JpegImage.LoadFromFile('test.jpg');
  finally
   JpegImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How do you see the error? Is it an exception you get? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499- Error 53 is: The network path was not found.

Comment: Is the file on disk? Can you open it with Windows?

Comment: `Exception EJPEG in module myprogram.exe at 002F744F. JPEG error #53`

Comment: The image is not a JPEG.

Comment: Have a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520186/delphi-jpeg-error-53

Comment: Maybe Image1.Picture.SaveToFile save the image in the original format that was used to load it, regardless of the file extension provided. To verify that, using Windows Explorer, change the extension from jpg to the extension of the original file (If you loaded a bmp file, change extension to bmp) and try to load it with Windows Explorer.

Comment: Your code assumes that saving the image with a .jpg extension automagically converts it into a valid JPEG file. This is not the case. If you want to save from the `TImage.Picture` to a JPEG, you should do it explicitly by creating a JPEGImage, assigning the `TImage.Picture` to that `TJPEGImage` (which will convert it if needed), and the saving it to file with a `.jpg` extension.